# Expect other parameters in EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

Is there an easy way to do something like that with EasyMock?

```
Object a, b, c;
expect(a.getB("string1")).andReturn(a).anyTimes();
expect(a.getB("string2")).andReturn(b).anyTimes();
expect(a.getB(<ANYTHING_ELSE>)).andReturn(c).anyTimes();
```

Or should I implement my own implementation of `IArgumentMatcher`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`andAnswer`](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/2.5/org/easymock/IExpectationSetters.html#andAnswer%28org.easymock.IAnswer%29) method of `expect`:

```
expect(a.getB((String)anyObject())).andAnswer(new IAnswer<MyClass>() {
    public MyClass answer() {        
        String in = (String) getCurrentArguments()[0];
        switch(in) {
            case: "string1":
                return a;
            case: "string2":
                return b;
            default:
                return c;
        }
    }
});
```

N.B: Switch on `String` requires Java 7.